# How to (Over Blogger.com ) generate One Time Dynamic Link to my Ebook hosted @ DropBox?

Tags: php, url, dynamic, blogger, blogs

I have My Free Blog @ Blogger.com and Also My Ebook is hosted at My Free Dropbox
So Now I need to create a One Time Dynamic Link (Expires after One Click ) to My Ebook and to put that Link @ My Blog

Answer (score 0):

I think you could utilize [1ty.me](https://1ty.me/). If you have custom server, you can write your own script, but you are using Blogger and Dropbox, thus I assume you expect some existing service.

Comment: It will not work because any one can copy the link after redirecting to it

Comment: I don't think there is any perfect solution without custom server or hosting. @gigi